# Is there a way to send a message to a user without making him type anything with a discord py bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots, private-messaging

I know that you can send a private message to someone with `await client.send_message(user)`. But as i know it only works if the person u wanna send a message to typed a command. I want my bot to send a message to someone who isn’t even in a server with him. I want my command like this: -send private message name#0000. I wonder if it’s even possible to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think its possible to message someone who doesnt share a same server as the bot

but you can use

```
await client.get_user(userid).send(msg)
```

to send a message to the user even if they didnt invoke a command

Answer (score 0):

you could add that to your on_ready function by defining user and passing it to the function

```
user = "user#1234"
```

and then using the same method but that would only work if you restart your bot.